# compute missing value based on specific row ID, only on columns with NA

Tags: r

I would like to compute a missing value by way of taking the average of the lead and lag rows, for a specific row. In this example, year 2001.

```
df = data.frame(year = c(2000, 2001, 2002),
                 A = c(2, NA, 3),
                 B = c(2, 2, 3),
                 C = c(3, NA, 2))
```

have tried `case_when(year == 2001, is.na(.) ~ (lead(.) + lag(.) )/ 2)` but cant figure out how to change or mutate all of the 2001 rows in place for all instances of NA. Imagine many columns, some filled, some not!

Thoughts? And thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You were going in the right direction. The problem is that you don't want to change the year column but A, B, and C values. In this case, you want to change A and C. See below a fix to the solution that you posted.

#### Solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:C, ~case_when( is.na(.x) ~ (lead(.x) + lag(.x) )/ 2,
                                 TRUE ~ .x)))
```

#### Output

```
  year   A B   C
1 2000 2.0 2 3.0
2 2001 2.5 2 2.5
3 2002 3.0 3 2.0
```

PS: @akrun provided an elegant solution as well. See their comment to this solution below.

Comment: `coalesce` can be used here `df %>% mutate(across(A:C, ~ coalesce(.x, rowMeans(cbind(lead(.x), lag(.x)), na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: how would you apply a change in the row itself to these solutions? vs what these seem to do, which is treat every NA in the data table. thanks for pointing out my missing .X !

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution using `transpose` from `data.table`:

```
df2 <- data.table::transpose(df,make.names = "year",keep.names = "name")

  name 2000 2001 2002
1    A    2   NA    3
2    B    2    2    3
3    C    3   NA    2
```

You can then use ifelse on the column:

```
df2$`2001` <-  ifelse(is.na(df2$`2001`),(df2$`2000`+df2$`2002`)/2,df2$`2000`)
```

And transform back

```
data.table::transpose(df2,keep.names = "year",make.names = "name")

  year   A B   C
1 2000 2.0 2 3.0
2 2001 2.5 2 2.5
3 2002 3.0 3 2.0
```

Another `data.table` way, similar to what you did:

```
df %>% setDT()

df[,lapply(.SD,function(x){
  fifelse(year == 2001 & is.na(x),(lead(x) + lag(x))/2,x)
}),.SDcols = c("A","B","C")]

     A B   C
1: 2.0 2 3.0
2: 2.5 2 2.5
3: 3.0 3 2.0
```